# Unable to bind service (attempts always return false). Why?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to wrap my head around the android bluetooth API by adapting [this half-finished example project](https://github.com/Nithinjith/LEKotlin-Android) to get it working on a BLE heart rate peripheral (the stock HR example from Espressif, running on an ESP32 dev board).

My problem is that I am unable to bind the `Service` that manages the BLE connection; calling `bindService` always returns `false` (see commented line in `initBLEService` in code snippet below). I am unable to understand why, nor how to get the service running properly. Help?

Here's how I'm managing the BLE connection:

```
object BLEConnectionManager {

private val TAG = "BLEConnectionManager"
private var mBLEService: BLEService? = null
private var isBind = false
private val mServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
    override fun onServiceConnected(componentName: ComponentName, service: IBinder) {
        mBLEService = (service as BLEService.LocalBinder).getService()
        Log.i(TAG, "BLEConnectionManager.onServiceConnected mBLEService = $mBLEService")
        if (!mBLEService?.initialize()!!) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize")
        }
    }
    override fun onServiceDisconnected(componentName: ComponentName) {
        mBLEService = null
    }
}

fun initBLEService(context: Context) {
    try {
        if (mBLEService == null) {
            val gattServiceIntent = Intent(context, BLEService::class.java)
            if (context != null) {
                // BELOW LINE ALWAYS RETURNS false. WHY?
                isBind = context.bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection,
                    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
                Log.i(TAG, "BLEConnectionManager.initBLEService isBind = $isBind")
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.message)
    }
}

fun connect(deviceAddress: String): Boolean {
    var result = false
    Log.i(TAG, "BLEConnectionManager.connect (to $deviceAddress) and mBLEService is $mBLEService")
    if (mBLEService != null) result = mBLEService!!.connect(deviceAddress)
    return result
}
// ...etc
```

And here's what's going on in the main activity onCreate:

```
if (!BLEDeviceManager.isEnabled()) {
     val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
     startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
}
BLEConnectionManager.initBLEService(this@MainActivity)
```

And I attempt to connect with a button in the main activity:

```
private fun connectDevice() {
    Handler().postDelayed({
        BLEConnectionManager.initBLEService(this@MainActivity)
        if (BLEConnectionManager.connect(mDeviceAddress)) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "DEVICE CONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "DEVICE CONNECTION FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }, 1000)
}
```

The BLEService class is unchanged from the [original code](https://github.com/Nithinjith/LEKotlin-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/np/lekotlin/blemodule/BLEService.kt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh. I didn't realize that the service must be declared in the manifest file to be available to the component for binding. Add:

```
<service android:name=".blemodule.BLEService"></service>
```